# ConEmu with Notepad++ - Open new files always in the same tab

Tags: notepad++, conemu

So I'm using ConEmu with TotalCommander, I've also created a new task for Notepad++ which I use as external viewer in TotalCommander.

When I open a file it always opens a new Notepad++ tab within ConEmu, but I want to open that file always within the same Notepad++ tab that is already open, not always create a new tab, how do I do that?

Comment: Not quite sure if Notepad++ supports DDE, if it does, that may be an option. Seems like N. tries to find prev.instance among the top level windows, but it can't - prev.instance is a child.

Comment: I know this is an old post but this is still an issue today and it is a real PITA that prevents (at least for me) being able to dock NPP in conemu because every single notepad open command breaks the npp setting and forces open a new top-level NPP instance, including all plugins, all files already opened (if you have session mgr running) etc.  It would be awesome to find some way to even fudge this to be able to present NPP as "running" to be able to maintain single-instance and open new files in the one running docked in conemu.

Comment: Note I have also opened an issue with the NPP team at `https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4850` because ultimately I fully agree that the PID and handle remain the same the window has simply been flagged as a child.  Ultimately, the simple loop to find existing instance to honor single-instance mode is flawed and needs a few more lines of code like every other app to adequately loop through ALL window handles, recursively including child and activate notepad++.exe, regardless of window state or parent.

Comment: One last comment - I have also located the offending code and have some potential easy code fix suggestions I will pose to the NPP team (and plan on setting up a build env myself just to go ahead and submit a proper PR).  Either way, I know I can come up with a rebuild of NPP that will dock in conemu, and do what everyone has been asking for years - find itself correctly, even when made a child of conemu, and simply activating a new NPP tab in the single docked instance for any calls for a file edit.